# Receiving a 404 Error on AWS Lambda Post Request

Tags: api, http, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to use an AWS Lambda function as a scheduling agent to post recurring payments to a payment api (USIO). The function used to make the post request is as follows:

```
const doPostRequest = async (data) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      host: "api.securepds.com",
      path: "/2.0/payments.svc/JSON/SubmitTokenPayment",
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'https://application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      }
    };

    //create the request object with the callback with the result
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      resolve(JSON.stringify(res.statusCode));
    });

    // handle the possible errors
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    });

    console.log(req)
    //do the request
    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));

    //finish the request
    req.end();
  });
};
```

where data is an object like so:

```
var obj = `{"MerchantID":"${merchantId}",
"Login":"${merchantLogin}",
"Password":"${merchantPassword}",
"Token": "${token}",
"Amount": "${result.Items[i]['amount']}"
```

and the post function is called like so:

```
await doPostRequest(obj)
  .then(result => console.log(`Status code: ${result}`))
  .catch(err => console.log(`Error doing the request for the event: ${JSON.stringify(event)} => ${err}`));
```

Despite verifying that obj inputs are all valid, I continue to receive a "Status code: 404" logged when the POST request is made.  No VPCs have been added to the lambda function.

I'm new to making api calls via lambda, but was able to receive a 200 status code when testing the function with a different api address.  Wondering what may be causing the 404 status code in this instance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having an issue, but it appears the JSON may be invalid.

When I tried to validate the JSON on JSONLint it failed as it was expecting an extra `}` at the end.

The format below was validated when I took off the single `'` and added a bracket at the end.

```
 {
    "MerchantID": "${merchantId}",
    "Login": "${merchantLogin}",
    "Password": "${merchantPassword}",
    "Token": "${token}",
    "Amount": "${result.Items[i]['amount']}"
 }
```

You can find the link to JSONLint [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

If it's still an issue, could you send the JSON as it's being sent to the endpoint? Also, which endpoint are you trying to call?